# Can I use my raspberry pi 2 OS for raspberry pi 3 directly?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-3

I recently got hold of the Raspberry Pi 3, and wonder if I safely can use the same SD card loaded with Raspbian that I currently use for my Raspberry Pi 2 on the RP3 as well.

The reason for wanting to use the same SD card (or clone the distro into a new one, which is what I plan on doing), is because I recently have gone through a fairly hairy and long setup of ROS on my RP2, and would not want to go through that again unless I actually have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you update to the latest `apt-get update` `apt-get dist-upgrade` the answer is **Yes**.

I am doing so now.

It is sensible to ensure unique hostnames if you plan to use both on the same network at the same time.

There are certain settings which might change this e.g. static IP addresses. These are generally not best practice.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the potential network issues. I will certainly have to assign a new hostname for the RPi 3.